# How can I prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n) / \ln(n+1) = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> How can I prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n) / \ln(n+1) = 1$ ?

I have looked through all my logarithm rules to find something useful, but the only thing that comes close is $\ln(a/b) = \ln(a)-\ln(b)$.

How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

Write

$$\ln(n+1)=\ln\left(n\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)=\ln n+\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)$$

**Edit**
We have
$$\require{cancel}\frac{\ln n}{\ln(n+1)}=\frac{\ln n}{\ln n+\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)}=\frac{\cancelto{1}{\ln n}}{\cancel{\ln n}\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\ln n}\right)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1
$$

Comment: So we have that their different approach $0$ ? And from this we can conclude that the quotient approach $1$ ?

Comment: You can factor by $\ln n$ and simplify numerator and denominator. Try it!

Comment: Im not completely sure what you mean. I write $$\ln(n+1) = \ln(n) + \ln(1+1/n) \Rightarrow \ln(n+1)-\ln(n) = \ln(1+1/n) \Rightarrow \ln((n+1)/n) = \ln(1+1/n)$$ ?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. Thank you very much for your very clever answer.

Comment: You're welcome@NicolasLykkeIversen

Answer (score 4):

If you apply L'Hopital's Rule, you get

\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{ \ln(n+1)} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/n}{1/(n+1)} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n} \\
&= 1
\end{align}

Comment: Is this rule also valid when $n$ is a natural number and not a real number ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen, yes, but I am not sure why you would think might be a problem.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen, actually are you asking how to find the limit or to actually *prove* it is equal to $1$? I think I may have misread your intentions in the question.

Comment: I want to prove it :)

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen, actually I think we can still use this result to 'cheat' a bit. By L'Hopital's Rule, your limit is equal to $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n}. $$ Thus we if set $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon >0$, then we have established $$ \left |\frac{n+1}{n} - 1 \right | < \epsilon $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Nameless. Nice to know I can you this procedure another time.